# Rescaling to (0,1) certain columns from Pandas Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scaling

I have the following type of dataframe:

```
  Channel   Region  Fresh   Milk    Grocery Frozen  Detergents_Paper    Delicassen
0   2         3     12669   9656    7561    214        2674             1338
1   2         3     7057    9810    9568    1762       3293             1776
2   2         3     6353    8808    7684    2405       3516             7844
3   1         3     13265   1196    4221    6404       507              1788
4   2         3     22615   5410    7198    3915       1777             5185
```

I would like to do two things:

1) Be able to rescale only certain columns and not all of them in order for them to be between 0,1. I would like to select only certain columns but not by their name but by their position. Imagine I want to change 200 and don't want to write all of them.

The code I tried was:

```
df /= df.max()
```

But it makes all of the columns to be between (0,1) and not only the ones I want. And I can't find a way to select a part of them only.

2) I would also like to re scale the columns but not between them, what I mean is I would like to make a scale only for milk and another one only for frozen, for instance.

I want to re scale each one, for example divide between 100 because they are too big, but maybe for another column I would like to divide it between 10 cause 100 is too much. How would I do that?

Comment: you can sub-select cols from your df by passing a list of cols, for instance `df[['Milk','Frozen']] = df[['Milk','Frozen']]/df[['Milk','Frozen']].max()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For 1, you can select a list of columns like this:

```
df[['Milk','Frozen','Grocery']]
```

Therefore, to rescale only those three columns, use:

```
df[['Milk','Frozen','Grocery']] -= df[['Milk','Frozen','Grocery']].min()
df[['Milk','Frozen','Grocery']] /= df[['Milk','Frozen','Grocery']].max()
```

This method already scales your column independantly from each other if this is what your second question means.

EDIT:

If you want to select the 200 first columns of your dataframe, you can use `df.columns` which gives you the list of your columns:

```
df[df.columns[:200]] -= df[df.columns[:200]].min()
df[df.columns[:200]] /= df[df.columns[:200]].max()
```

the `max` method on pandas on a dataframe returns a list of the max of each column. Therefore if you use the above code, you'll have max values in each of the columns exactly equal to 1.

If you don't want to divide it by the max of each column but first column by `n1`, second column by `n2` you can use the same notation:

```
df[df.columns[:4]] /= [n1,n2,n3,n4]
```

Comment: For 1) I would like to select only certain columns but not by their name but by their position. Imagine I want to change 200 and don't want to write all of them. 

For 2) I want to re scale each one, for example divide between 100 because they are too big, but maybe for another column I would like to divide it between 10 cause 100 is too much. How would I do that?

I'll add this in my question too.

Comment: I've edited my answer, does it better fit your needs?

Comment: There should be a default option in pandas to do this. Something like `df.rescale(min=0,max=1)`.

Comment: From what I've seen so far there isn't. Although there is `MinMaxScaler` in `sklearn.preprocessing` which is widely used.

Comment: This answer doesn't scale over 0,1 but over (min/max),1

Comment: Thanks for pointing my mistake out, I corrected it. Better late than never!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution for a single column which does actually rescale over 0,1:

```
a = [5,15,25,35,45,50,55,65,75,85,95]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=a, columns=['a'])
df['rescale'] = (df['a'] - min(df['a'])) / (max(df['a']) - min(df['a']))
```

Also a numpy method:

```
import numpy as np
rescale = (a - np.min(a))/np.ptp(a)
```